# Replacing Side Indicator in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I've hit a dead end and I'd like your expertise on the subject :)

I have 2 Files.

1. Printer name and their Driver - with a `NoteProperty` of `Name` and `DriverName`
2. Printer Drivers - with a `NoteProperty` of `Name` (The driver name) and `MajorVersion`

The whole point of it is to know which printer has what type of driver
as in:

**Printer DriverName MajorVersion**

I know that the output of `Get-Driver` just gets the driver name and the printer name. Whilst `Get-DriverPrinter` gets the driver and MajorVersion.

I'd like to compare the two commands, and then merge the outputs into 1 file where the `SideIndicator` is replaced with `MajorVersion`.

So far I've made this:

```
#This is the Printer Drives File - Has Name(DriverName) and MajorVersion(type) fields
$Drivers = Import-Csv .\PrinterDrivers.csv

#This is the Printer File - Has Printer Name and Driver Name
$PrinterNames = Import-Csv .\Printers.csv

#This Compares between the 2 objects
$Comparison = Compare-Object -ReferenceObject $PrinterNames -DifferenceObject $Drivers -PassThru -IncludeEqual
{ Foreach ($Device in $Comparison) {
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "==" ) {
        $_.SideIndicator = $Drivers.MajorVersion
    }
        if ($_.SideIndicator -eq "<=") {
            $_.SideIndicator = $Drivers.MajorVersion
        }
    }
}
```

when I call `$Comparison`

It shows as this:

```
YAHOD-NM                      HP Universal Printing PCL 6        ==   
SEC30CDA7AE44AC               Samsung M337x 387x 407x Series     ==   
NHR-SMEFAKED                  Lexmark MX710 Series XL            ==   
NHR-Madrichim                 Samsung SCX-5835_5935X Series PCL6 ==   
NHR-MADARIA                   Samsung M337x 387x 407x Series     ==   
NHR-08263                     Samsung ML-331x Series             ==   
NHR-01954                     Lexmark Mono XPS Class Driver      ==   
NHR-01250                     Samsung SCX-483x 5x3x Series       ==
```

Is it possible to make remove `SideIndicator` and show `MajorVersion` instead?

Or...I have to create the original `printer.csv` with just 1 Column `DriverName`, run it against the `PrinterDrivers.csv` and then rerun the comparison versus the original `printer.csv` that has 2 columns?

Comment: If you're replacing the SideIndicator in 2 out of 3 cases, what is the point of the comparison? Are you interested in "=>" only?

Comment: i am having an ambiguity in the comparison. Can you show the file content and the expected output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't look like you're actually interested in doing comparison.

You're current code (even with the comparison) doesn't make that much sense as you'd assign all driver versions instead of just one in case it would work.

I'm assuming that your printer name is what you're actually interested in. So you could loop through each and lookup the information in the drivers data file.

```
# This is the Printer Drives File - Has Name(DriverName) and MajorVersion(type) fields
$drivers = Import-Csv .\PrinterDrivers.csv
# This is the Printer File - Has Printer Name and Driver Name
$printerNames = Import-Csv .\Printers.csv

foreach($printer in $printerNames){
    $driverVersion = $drivers | Where driverName -eq $printer.driverName
    $printer | Select-Object -Property @{Name = "Printer Name"; Expression = {$printer.Name}}, @{Name = "Driver Version"; Expression={$driverVersion}} 
}
```

Comment: It's appreciated but rather than posting a thank you [checkout what you should be doing if someone answers your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

The `Compare-Object` surly is for comparing similar things to find the differences, you seem to be trying to use it to do a lookup. Would a hash not be a better fit:

```
$Drivers = @{} 
Import-Csv .\PrinterDrivers.csv | % {$Drivers[$_.DriverName] = $_.MajorVersion}
$Printers = Import-Csv .\Printers.csv | % {
  New-Object psobject -property @{
    PrinterName = $_.Name
    DriverName = $_.DriverName
    MajorVersion = $Drivers[$_.DriverName]
  }
}
```